# How to pass multiple variables from parent class to child class functions automatically using extract();?

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, global-variables

I'm not sure how to code this exactly, but I can surely say it better I believe than my code indicates.

I want to [extract();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) vars from my parent class and have those vars be automatically available to the functions in the child class.

Currently, I have to call the extract(); function within each child class function for the vars to be available. This is what I'm trying to reduce, the extract(); call each time to just one time within the child class.

I'm a still new to the __construct(); method as I started out with just calling functions statically. But I tried to study and make sense of this, but I ONLY find articles online that show how to pass SINGLE vars to other functions from the __construct();. I don't find any articles on how to pass multiple vars at once. Specifically using the extract();.

Can this be done?

My end goal is simply to reduce the writing of "**parent::**" for each var in the child class. So when needed I can extract the vars and simply write `$var` instead of `parent::$var`.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Concept One
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Parent_Vars {

    public static function get_vars() {

        $vars = array(
            'var_1' => 'var_1',
            'var_2' => 'var_2',
            'var_3' => 'var_3',
        );
        return $vars;

    }

}

class Parent_Vars extends class Child_Vars {

    public static $instance;

    static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        parent::get_vars();
    }

    // This method DOES NOT work

    public static function echo_var_method_1() {

        //extract(parent::get_vars()); If I uncomment this, my vars below will work
        // But I don't want to call extract(parent::get_vars()); for every function I need. 
        //  I would like the vars to already be available from the __construct();
        echo $var_1; // returns error = undefined var
        echo $var_2; // returns error = undefined var
        echo $var_3; // returns error = undefined var
        echo parent::$var_1; // Works, but I'm trying to reduce writing parent:: everytime
        echo parent::$var_2; // Works, but I'm trying to reduce writing parent:: everytime
        echo parent::$var_3; // Works, but I'm trying to reduce writing parent:: everytime

    }

    // This method DOES work

    public static function echo_var_method_2() {

        extract(parent::get_vars()); // I'm trying NOT to call the var extract for each function, but for the whole class at once
        echo $var_1; // echoes "var_1" !! No need to write parent:: everytime for the vars
        echo $var_2; // echoes "var_2" !! No need to write parent:: everytime for the vars
        echo $var_3; // echoes "var_3" !! No need to write parent:: everytime for the vars

    }

}

$object = new Child_Vars();
Child_Vars::echo_var_method_1();
Child_Vars::echo_var_method_2();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Concept Two - just slightly different with the parent class having its own __construct(); and the child __construct(); calling the parent __construct();
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Parent_Vars {

    public function __construct() {
        extract(self::get_vars());
    }

    public static function get_vars() {

        $vars = array(
            'var_1' => 'var_1',
            'var_2' => 'var_2',
            'var_3' => 'var_3',
        );
        return $vars;

    }

}

class Parent_Vars extends class Child_Vars {

    public static $instance;

    static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // This method DOES NOT work

    public static function echo_var_method_1() {

        //extract(parent::get_vars()); If I uncomment this, my vars below will work
        // But I don't want to call extract(parent::get_vars()); for every function I need. 
        //  I would like the vars to already be available from the __construct();
        echo $var_1; // returns error = undefined var
        echo $var_2; // returns error = undefined var
        echo $var_3; // returns error = undefined var
        echo parent::$var_1; // Works, but I'm trying to reduce writing parent:: everytime
        echo parent::$var_2; // Works, but I'm trying to reduce writing parent:: everytime
        echo parent::$var_3; // Works, but I'm trying to reduce writing parent:: everytime

    }

    // This method DOES work

    public static function echo_var_method_2() {

        extract(parent::get_vars()); // I'm trying NOT to call the var extract for each function, but for the whole class at once
        echo $var_1; // echoes "var_1" !! No need to write parent:: everytime for the vars
        echo $var_2; // echoes "var_2" !! No need to write parent:: everytime for the vars
        echo $var_3; // echoes "var_3" !! No need to write parent:: everytime for the vars

    }

}

$object = new Child_Vars();
Child_Vars::echo_var_method_1();
Child_Vars::echo_var_method_2();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish but my first impression is that this is really really bad OO practice (in fact with the static keyword appearing everywhere it's probably not OO at all!  Static methods are a code smell for attempting to apply non-OO thinking to an OO model).  If you declare a variable in a superclass then it's automatically available in the subclass (unless you declare it private).  Missing around with extract shouldn't be necessary, and it's definitely not recommended.

Comment: I should add that I don't want to make these global variables, available everywhere, but just available to the child class and its functions when needed. And I hope this makes sense. I'm not sure how PHP is gathering the vars, but from my understanding for each time I call the extract(); php will extract ALL those vars. I don't want to do that when only a few vars may be used from that extraction. So I want to reduce calling the extract as much as possible, which is why I want to call it once for the whole class when needed. Hope that makes sense. - Oh, ok. Just saw your response. @GordonM

Comment: For the OO static keyword it is. I understand that as I said that I started only calling functions statically because I don't yet totally understand the obj logic. But I know that a construct can make some things avialable automatically on the the instance creation, so that was my logic for trying a construct. But ultimately I just want my extracted vars to be available to my child class function.

Comment: Why don't you just create a `__get` method that looks in the array, instead of extracting them into variables?

Comment: @Barmar well for that I could just call `parent::` which is what I am already doing. I have all my vars already as public static $var; But I was trying to find a way to pull all those vars into another class and not have to write parent::$var. Only because I notice that parent::$var is becoming very repetitive. It probably is not that big of an issue, but I had the thought and wanted to dig into it, especially because I found not articles on the concept, but maybe that is why, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract is very dodgy when using with OO. It would be more advisable (and faster execution time wise) to run a foreach and assign $this->$key = $value (since they would be dynamic anyway you could also use magic functions to create getters and setters). If you insist on using extract you should have a lok a comment made by " FredLawl " on the same extract() page of php manual.

Update:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $this->$key = $value
        }
    }
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass
{
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }
}

$instance = new MyClass2($variableArray);

$xtractedVar = $instance->variableKey;
```

You can use this base principle to play around and work out a solution that you need.

Comment: Ok. Well if it is not advisable, then I don't want to do it nor learn how to do it, that way. I'm still learning so this was just the idea I have with the knowledge I have. Can you give me a code example of what you mean to try? Faster execution is also what I want and trying to reduce code that I notice becomes repetitive. Right now I call each $var as parent::$var, I'm trying to just write $var, but also make all those $vars available to the class when needed with one call. In theory is it faster to just call parent::$var?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're understanding OO very well and are trying to apply a non-OO way of thinking.  An object in PHP (and most other class-based OO languages) is a collection of data and an associated collection of methods that manipulate that data.  When you create a subclass of a given class, you create a new type of object that extends the collection of variables and the collection of applicable methods.

You also don't quite seem to understand the difference between a class variable (common to all classes) and an instance variable (a variable whose value is unique to a given instance of a class).

For instance variables, any non-private variable is automatically available to the subclass via $this.

```
class SuperClass {
    protected $var = "";
    public function showVar ()
    {
        echo $this -> var . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function setVal ($newVal)
    {
        $this -> var = $newVal;
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public function showVarInString ()
    {
        echo "Hello, I'm a subclass with value " . $this -> var;
    }
}

$a = new SuperClass ();
$b = new SubClass ();
$a -> setVal (1);
$b -> setVal (4);
$a -> showVar (); // "1"
$b -> showVar (); // "4"
$b -> showVarInString (); // "Hello, I'm a subclass with value 4"
```

Class variables, aka static variables are common to all instances of a class and are accessed with static:: instead of $this

```
class SuperClass
{
    protected static $var = 1234;
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    public function showVar ()
    {
        echo static::$var . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I alluded to the non-OO skillset because I've only been using classes to protect functions and use more general function names and also extended certain class elements to child classes. I'm not using __construct() because I don't understand it yet. I've looked over it several, several times, but I don't understand it yet, nor do I see it's purpose for what I am doing.

Comment: I can't use $this as it stands because I always get the error... Using $this when not in object context... I'll just stick to what I am doing then and look more over the OOP later on again. Also my vars have to be public or they will error, so I do understand that. I was trying o write some code more relevant to what I was actually trying to achieve.